# Trouble collecting the callback response from an ipfs.util.addFromFS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, callback, ipfs

I am trying to store the body of a callback response in MongoDB. More specifically, I am executing [/ipfs/add](https://ipfs.io/docs/api/#apiv0add) as this meteor method on the "main.js - server" file.

```
ipfsAdd: function(){
    var result = ipfs.util.addFromFs('/home/eruguru/CreativeCommonPlace/server/landscape.jpg');
    return (result);
},
```

I then imported it to this meteor js template that executes when an HTML button is clicked.

```
Template.ipfsAdd.events({
    'click .ipfsButton': function(event){
        Meteor.call("ipfsAdd", function(err, res)
        {console.log(err, res)});
    }
})
```

I know that the function works as I get the expected output in the console as part of an undefined object

```
{
    hash: "QmW1xtbLAmS9TBfmeHnhNC7cavLEcxDPHa2MfJtRSmy8dC",
    path: "landscape.jpg",
    size: 132713
}
```

So I guess where I am stuck is how to define this object as a variable and then collect it as part of my MongoDB.

My ultimate goal here is to have a table where the first column is a list of file names, a second column for the file size, third with this hash from the undefined callback response object.

Apologies in advance if I have posted this in an incorrect place or made any other rookie mistakes. I believe this is my first question on stack exchange.

Thank you very much for any help at all!

Comment: I would also like to add that because this is my first question, I am more than open to feed back on how I presented this question.

Title phrasing. general presentation and ease of understanding, if it was well communicated or not.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few days I figured out my problem and if anyone needs help with a similar problem this should work for you. Just keep in mind that IPFS is in alpha and their documentation and API could change at any time.

After mousing over the fields (hash, path, and size) in the "res" console.log output I noticed that I got pop up showing '["0"].hash'. So all I needed to modify my Template.ipfsAdd.events script.

```
Template.ipfsAdd.events({
  'click .ipfsButton': function(event){
    Meteor.call("ipfsAdd",
    function(err, res){
      //console.log(err, res)
      ListofFiles.insert({
        text: res["0"].hash,
      });
    }
    );
  }
})
```

Where "ListOfFiles" is the name of my MongoDB I wish to add the info to. this also works with the path and size fields. If you add multiple files in one ipfsAdd function just change the res index to the corresponding file.